# What network protocol would a typical CI/CD pipeline use?

Tags: http, continuous-integration, protocols, pipeline, continuous-deployment

As the title says, I am curious to know if the protocol being used would typically be FTP or if HTTP is sufficent. 
 What protocol would you use, if you were to build your own pipeline, to transfer the file from 
`version control -> server(s) making up pipeline -> server receiving and running the artifact`.
Maybe I'm overthinking/overcomplicating, and HTTP is the protocol being used to transfer the artifact?

I've searched around for any answers, but not found any information regarding what protocol is typically being used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either protocols to transer files/artifact if that is what you are asking.